# Is there way to set scale animation to google map api 2 marker

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to set a scale in and scale out animation to marker. I want to scale in the marker icon for 1 second and scale out for 1 second...and keep continue this animation sequence. I have done this in Ios im wondering if this is possible in android .

Answer (score 0):

You have the method

GoogleMap.moveCamera (CameraUpdate update)

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)

Here the docs to GoogleDevelopers for moving the camera in a Google Map
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#moving_the_camera

Comment: no that's not what im looking for. "I want to scale in the marker icon for 1 second and scale out for 1 second...and keep continue this animation sequence"

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the icon programatically?
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setIcon(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptor)